# Which marginal likelihood is maximized in empirical Bayes?

Tags: empirical-bayes

I am reading up on empirical Bayes, and I am finding it really hard to understand what exactly is going on.
As far as I understand, it is based on maximizing the marginal likelihood of the data (so integrate out the prior of the parameter, such that the marginal likelihood of the data depends on the hyperparameters). But I am struggling with incorporating possible covariates that might influence the prior such that this is dependent on the specific observation.

I think I am just a bit confused as to which marginal likelihood we are actually trying to maximize when using empirical Bayes.

I hope this question makes some sort of sense, and that someone can help me along at least with an overall understanding.

Thanks!